# Is it possible to infer this generic type, for type-safe callback?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Is there a way to get rid of the CS0411 error below, and not have to explicitly state the type?
Also do not want to have to use reflection.

```
var router = new ExampleRouter();
var controller = new ExampleWebController();

// compiles, but not elegant
router.MapPost<string>("/api/bar", controller.ProcessString);

// error CS0411: can't infer type
router.MapPost("/api/foo", controller.ProcessString);

class ExampleWebController {
    public ExampleWebController() { }
    public bool ProcessNumber(int v) { return true; }
    public bool ProcessString(string v) { return true; }
}

class ExampleRouter {
    public ExampleRouter() { }
    public void MapPost<TBody>(string path, Func<TBody, bool> handler) {
        // Save typeof(TBody), since TBody will actually be a class type we
        // will construct for each callback
        var body_type = typeof(TBody);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not unless you have a TBody parameter.

Comment: @aybe sadly, that's impossible bcause TBody can only be constructed by the router, once an http request comes in.  And of course it would look even uglier.

Comment: However, if you do something like `MapPost<T>(string, Func<T>)` then inject your constructor like `MapPost("abcd", s => new MyStuff()) this will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as someone's mentioned in comments one solution is to pass in the data as a parameter:

```
public void MapPost<TBody>(string path, Func<TBody, bool> handler, Tbody data) {

   object dataType = data.GetType();

}
```

Comment: This would be better if it was defined as `Type dataType = data.GetType();`, since we know that `GetType` always returns an instance of `System.Type`. From that you could possibly create an instance of that type with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is "inelegant" as you've said, is because the order of your generic arguments specifies an input type (`TBody`) and an output type (`bool`). However, in your calls to `MapBody`, you are only providing methods that return `boolean` results, so that the compiler doesn't know what to use for the value of `TBody`.

This is the origin of the CS0411 error you are receiving. The only way around it is to provide a generic type argument at the point of call.

This is why this code works, and should be what you use going forward:

```
var router = new ExampleRouter();
var controller = new ExampleWebController();

// compiles, but not elegant
router.MapPost<string>("/api/bar", controller.ProcessString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a self answer here.  If I change it to this, the MapPost() code looks elegant, which was my goal.  HOWEVER, I have lost some compile time checking -- for example anything can be passed in as a "handler".  I will post [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638671/can-i-add-compile-time-checks-that-this-is-a-legal-handler-function-constraine) on how I refine this.

```
var router = new ExampleRouter();
var controller = new ExampleWebController();

// We will have to do runtime validation that controller.ProcessString is a
// legal callback (which isn't ideal, but still fine).
// An improvement would be to add some kind of generic constraints?
router.MapPost("/api/foo", controller.ProcessString);

class ExampleWebController {
    public ExampleWebController() { }
    public bool ProcessNumber(int v) { return true; }
    public bool ProcessString(string v) { return true; }
}

class ExampleRouter {
    public ExampleRouter() { }
    public void MapPost<TFunc>(string path, TFunc handler) {
        var func_type = typeof(TFunc);
        Console.WriteLine(func_type);  // Prints "System.Func"
        var args = func_type.GetGenericArguments();
        foreach (var arg in args) {
            // Prints "System.String", "System.Boolean"...awesome
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}
```